# How can I loop songs automatically by giving command only once

Tags: javascript, loops, bots, discord, discord.js

I have made a loop command. 
It repeats only once after giving the command and requires command again to repeat 
a second time.

```js
if(msg.content === '_loop'){
        let fetch = ops.active.get(msg.guild.id)
        if(!fetch.queue) return msg.channel.send("There is no song in the queue!")

        let ls = fetch.queue[0];
    //  cloning object
        const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ls));
        msg.channel.send("Loop Enabled!")

        while (fetch.queue.length == 1) {
            fetch.queue.push(clone);
        }
    };
```

I know its wrong, it only loops when I give command but I want to make it continuously loop after I run the command.

I have given the condition `(fetch.queue.length == 1)`

It only adds song to queue when I give the command.

How can I make it so it only requires the command to be ran once then loops continuously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think thats efficient way,

If `ops.active` is a collection, you can toggle loop in it

```
fetch.loop = !fetch.loop //if length == 1
```

And i assume you're using `connection.("end")`, if loop is enabled,
push the current song there

Comment: No problem.
Accept my answer to mark this question as solved